# Why do you not put a pronoun in front of chapter

Tags: grammar, american-english

I saw this phrase "In chapter 1 section 1". But I thought, "why do we not put a pronoun in front of chapter 1?" because, in the sentence, it's a specific chapter 1. Can anyone explain why? Thank you.

Comment: By _pronoun_ do you mean _article_? **Chapter One** is treated as a title. An author might write _In the previous chapter I mentioned..._, but _In Chapter 1 I mentioned..._

Comment: Same with "Book Two", "Volume 3", "Section 9", "Clause IV", "Rule 2", "Class 3B", "Year Four", "Grade Eight", and so on - versus "the second book", "the third volume", "the ninth section", "the fourth clause", "the second rule", "the fourth year", etc

Comment: "In" is not a pronoun.